# Handling similar checkbox values in .NET Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox

```
List<char> errorList = new List<char>();
        if (meetingErrorCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('M');
        if (ScheduledMachineDowntimeCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('S');
        if (ToolingCheckbox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('T');
        if (ProcessIssueCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('P');
        if (OperatorMaintenanceCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('O');
        if (VactionCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('V');
        if (CellLeadCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('C');
        if (WaitToolsCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('W');
        if (UnscheduledMaintenanceCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('U');
        if (WaitMaterialCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('A');
        if (WaitInspectionCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('I');
        if(AlternateDepartmentCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('D');
        if (TrainingCheckBox.Checked)
            errorList.Add('B');
```

Is there any way to make this.. cleaner? I thought about like using an interface or something, but it seems like there isn't an easier way with .NET Web Forms and the asp:CheckBox.

Basically I'm using this list to fill an intermediate table between 2 tables in a database and I'm wondering of there's a better way, since I still need to do a check on which box was checked regardless if I can iterate through all the boxes.

Comment: I can't give a full answer at the moment, but I would think you could have a CheckBoxList containing all of your CheckBoxes, and then loop over the list of CheckBoxes, check if they are checked, and then add the error code. I'd keep the error code in an attribute for each Checkbox, so you can pull them all easily while looping instead of having to check to see which checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to simplify this would be to rename all the checkboxes to error0, error1, error2, etc... and then iterate though them by doing this:

```
List<char> errorList = new List<char>();
int totalErrors = 13; //change accordingly
char[] errorId = new char['M', 'S', 'T', 'P', 'O', 'V', 'C', 'W', 'U', 'A', 'I', 'D', 'B'];
for(int i = 0; i < totalErrors; i++)
{
    string controlId = "error" + i.ToString();
    Control errorButton = FindControl(controlId);
    if(errorButton.Checked)
         errorList.add(char[i]);
}
```

If you use this just remember to make the id of the checkbox correspond to that element in the char[]. For example, the **element 0** in the char array I used is M, that means the checkbox you want to have give the error M, you would name **error0**. This code would allow you to add to the error list without having a huge list of if statements. And of course make sure to update the total error variable accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that is much neater. I didn't know about the find control function. I was trying to come up with some sort of map to link the two things but nothing was coming to mind.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is to use a Checkboxlist. You can manually add the values to it or choose a datasource to bind database values to it.

The following code will get the values which are checked:

```
foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
        //Whatever you want to do with item
}
```

Comment: This would work accept iterating through the checkboxes this way wouldnt allow you to know which check box youre on. And therefore he cant add a specific error character, since that is dependent on which checkbox it is.

Comment: @RetroChicken The error character can be the value for each item in checkboxlist. If the item is selected, then item.Value will give what op wants. This way the code remains same when there is a change in requirement to add/remove checkboxes and also less hard coding.